# can ajax be used on cgridview column

Tags: ajax, yii, onmouseover, cgridview, onmouseout

My cgridview has two columns ptid and mid. What i need to know is, can ajax be used on cgridview column?
Can i use onmouseover and onmouseout functions?
On the onmouseover event each mid values should be retrieved from db with an ajax call.
Can this be done and if so, how? Are there any code examples available i could use?

My output for cgridview is following

```
ptid    mid    
 1       1     
 2       2     
 1       10
```

Comment: This [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32840-yii-show-tooltip-in-cgridview-table-value/) for adding title to column. You can add ajax call in htmloptions array. You have to write own code to do ajax call.

Comment: @kumar_v sorry for the delay to reply .... and thanks:) l look to it